# Displaying some cells data depending on selected text from other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have an excel sheet which looks similar to below and with some more columns.

```
Area    Branch          Empolyees   Products    Shelfs
Area1   Area1 Branch1   10          Product 1   10
Area1   Area1 Branch2   5           Product 1   6
Area1   Area1 Branch3   8           Product 2   8
Area1   Area1 Branch4   9           Product 2   8
Area1   Area1 Branch5   7           Product 1   8
Area2   Area2 Branch1   10          Product 2   10
Area2   Area2 Branch2   6           Product 3   8
Area2   Area2 Branch3   8           Product 2   10
Area2   Area2 Branch4   13          Product 3   12
Area2   Area2 Branch5   5           Product 1   6
Area2   Area2 Branch6   8           Product 2   10
Area2   Area2 Branch7   7           Product 3   10
Area2   Area2 Branch8   5           Product 4   6
```

I want to have data in other sheet With respect to Product details. Where It gives me the count of Product 1 and so on.

I am able to get the count using countif function and it displays like below.

```
Product     Count
Product 1   6
Product 2   8
Product 3   4
Product 4   9
Product 5   10
Product 6   8
Product 7   8
Product 8   9
Product 9   7
Product 10  8
```

What I want is when I select "Product 1" It should display some selected columns data from sheet where complete data is available.

```
Branch                  Empolyees         Other
Area1 Branch1              10              abc
Area1 Branch2              5               xyz
Area1 Branch5              7               pqr
Area2 Branch5              5               wxy
```

Any ideas how which function we can use. I tried Vlookup but was not successful.

Comment: VBA is going to do this best.

Comment: @Raystafarian Thanks for info. But I have no idea how to use VBA. Any suggestion of VBA.